# Why custom aspects are shared between tasks while global is not?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

According to [alfresco forum](https://forums.activiti.org/content/persisting-model-data-between-tasks-alfresco) and [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300942/alfresco-show-task-fields-in-another-taskview-them) it is needed to define an aspect for sharing data between workflow tasks. But when I look at [bpmModel.xml](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/bpmModel.xml) in alfresco sources I see:

```
    <aspect name="bpm:assignees">
        <associations>

            <association name="bpm:assignees">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <many>true</many>
                </target>
            </association>

        </associations>
    </aspect>
```

Here we can see a `bpm:assignees` aspect which in theory should be shared between all task in alfresco. E.g. when one assignee to somebodies, all other assigned too. But actually it is not. So why `bpm:assignees` is not shared between all task, while custom defined aspect is?

Comment: Its's shared but the assignment is related to what you have set in your bpmn file for the property: "activiti:assignee"

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure what do you mean by this.

> when one assignee to somebodies, all other assigned too

Let me try to make things bit clear for you.

**bpm:assignee--->** Points to single user and when you want to assign task to single user you use this aspect

**bpm:assignees-->** Used when you want to assign task to more then one users.

Now you can see these aspects are explictly added to respective tasks in workflowModel.xml while defining task based on type of task.

Ex.

```
  <type name="wf:submitParallelReviewTask">
     <parent>wf:submitConcurrentReviewTask</parent>
     <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>bpm:assignees</aspect>
     </mandatory-aspects>
  </type>
```